# Django Tweepy File

Tags: python, django

I’m confused about this; instead of writing tweepy codes like-

```
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api=tweepy.API(auth)
```

In a new python file (IDLE). Can’t we write it in our views.py in django? Or we should create a new file in django app for the codes?

Comment: Voting to close as "not a question" because it's not at all clear what the question is…

Comment: @David: Looks like a valid question to me... He needs the Django conventions on separating code to different files explained to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a twitter_status.py file to my project and from views.py I call the update_twitter_status() method

twitter_status.py:

```
"""
Adds a tweet to the twitter account in settings.

Login to dev.twitter.com and add a desktop application
Add the keys and secrets for the added application to the settings file

Requires tweepy to be installed
https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy

"""
from django.conf import settings
from tweepy import *

class TwitterManager:
    def __get_api_handle(self):
        #Create OAuth object
        auth = OAuthHandler(settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)

        #Set access tokens
        auth.set_access_token(settings.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN, settings.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

        #Create API handle
        api = API(auth)

        return api

    def update_twitter_status(self, message):

        api = self.__get_api_handle()

        #Send update
        api.update_status(message)
```

Then in my views.py I just call the update_twitter_status(message) method

views.py:

```
from myproject.twitter_status import TwitterManager

def __update_twitter(message):
    twit_mgr = TwitterManager()
    twit_mgr.update_twitter_status(message)
```

Then whenever I want to tweet from my views.py I add this line

```
__update_twitter('I am tweeting')
```

If someone disagree on how I have implemeted the class or methods please I would be glad to get your feedback.